# Energy stored in a magnetically coupled circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, kirchhoffs-laws, magnetics

[image]

In the circuit shown, inductors $$L_1,L_2$$ are magnetically coupled with the mutual inductance being $$M$$. The red dots are for dot convention. Normally,the energy stored in such a circuit is $$\frac{1}{2}L_1i_1^2+\frac{1}{2}L_2i_2^2-Mi_1i_2$$ assuming current $$i_1-i_2$$ flows through $$L_1$$. Which implies both currents do not enter or exit the dot,hence the negative sign before $$M$$. Is the expression of energy I wrote correct?

Comment: Please convert your latex to have backslash added: \$\frac{1}{2}L_1i_1^2+\frac{1}{2}L_2i_2^2-Mi_1i_2\$ = `\$\frac{1}{2}L_1i_1^2+\frac{1}{2}L_2i_2^2-Mi_1i_2\$`||| Also, have you thought about using a simulator to check your idea?

Comment: @Andyaka I am not sure how to check,could you please whether what I wrote is correct?

Comment: See also the answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/500778/how-do-we-have-the-e-frac12l-1i-12-frac12l-2i-22-pm-mi-1i-2-ca?rq=1)